# Symfony: How to use the object from the form which is not yet in the database

Tags: php, forms, symfony, entity

I have three entities:

- Person
- Affiliation
- PersonAffiliation.

In the form, the user can create a new person and add some existing affiliations by clicking the button (add existing affiliations). The existing affiliations will be added in the PersonAffiliation entity.

The problem is that when the user starts creating a new person, he has to click add existing affiliation, and this person is not present in the database yet.

Is there a possibility to use the Person object from the form in the second form during the affiliations selection and then set the selected affiliations to this Person object and come back to the first form where the user has to submit the Person creation.

Tank you very much for your help.

Comment: I think this might be of some help. http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_collections.html

Comment: @PatrickJamesMcDougle, thank you very much. This seems interesting, but I would like to select the affiliations in a new form (or at least separated by all the person information as firstname lastname etc). I would like to have a scenario like tha because it an be that there are 10 or 20 affiliations and I would like to distinguish thiose affiliations from the other person information.

Comment: Can you have a multi-step form, one page for the person info, the other for affiliations? I don't really get why you want the affiliations in a separate form. Or why you can't just persist the entity with the info first, then add the affiliations later.

Comment: @Squazic, thanks. In fact, a person should have at least one affiiation, or more than one. If the user will first create the person and then add the affiliations, the user can cancel the procedure and then I will have a person without affiliations, so my goal was to insert everything at one time but without having the person bject in the same form.

Comment: You need to do it in one form or in multiple steps. There is no other way. You might be able to change the UI such that it looks like multiple steps while still doing the method outlined in my previous comment.

Comment: Thank you @PatrickJamesMcDougle, could you please answer this question and I will accept the answer.

Comment: Alright, I created an answer that sums all of this up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this two possible ways:

1. is called an embedded collection of forms. You can read about it in the [Symfony documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_collections.html). It isn't very easy to find if you don't exactly know what to call it.
2. Create the Person form and upon successful completion of a Person submission, then redirect to an Affiliation form with the person ID already filled in.